# ¿Como hacer un re-render a un componente de Angular 4?

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0, ionic-framework

Estoy iniciando con ionic y tengo un menuToggle que se muestra solo si el usuario esta logueado, el condicional esta en el template del menu y uso el *ngIf="login" para condicionar si se muestra o no, pero no he podido hacer que una vez el usuario se loguea se muestre el menú. Yo vengo del mundo de react, donde al hacer un cambio en el estado del componente el mismo se renderizaba segun sus cambios, pero en angular, como logro que al hacer el cambio de valores, se actualize la vista?

Comment: Johnny, buenas, bienvenido a la comunidad. Podrías agregar tu código? de todas manerás, podrías probar con un setTimeout, eso dispara un digest y hace que la vista se actualice. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me paso algo similar, cuando necesitaba que la navbar se oculte en el login, lo resolví definiendo un componente e instanciandolo en la plantilla de el controlador raíz de donde lo quieras usar (generalmente) `app.component.html`

Para mantener viva la configuración y poder manejar la visualización(fui un poco mas allá y agregue botones configurables, etc.) define un servicio junto con las variables que quieres mantener, despues ya solo sera llamar el servicio desde el controlador que definiste para consultar las variables asi como llamarlo al servicio desde cualquier controlador para modificar el estado de la misma, el cual automáticamente se vera reflejado.

```
// navbar.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { NavbarService } from './navbar.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit { 
    constructor (private navbarService: NavbarService) {}

    public mostrarPanel() {
        return this.navbarService.mostrarPanel;
    }
}
```

la plantilla

```
// navbar.component.html

<div *ngIf="mostrarPanel()">
</div>
```

el servicio

```
// navbar.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NavbarService { 
    public mostrarPanel: boolean;
}
```

No se si es la mejor forma, pero a partir de aquí se puede trabajar con un componente bastante dinámico, y lo manejas atraves de modificar las variables en el servicio

Comment: Excelente amigo, me funcionó muy bien. Entiendo que entonces en la plantilla no se apunta a un valor, mas bien, se apunta a un espacio en la memoria al dependerlo de una funcion.

Comment: Sucede que los servicios se mantienen en memoria una ves instanciado, la  funcion era solo un envoltorio para poder acceder al parametro del servicio.